# Is the support of a smooth function always open?

Tags: general-topology, functions

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological manifold and $f:X\to\Bbb R$ a smooth function. I need to know if the support of $f$, defined as $\text{supp}(f)=\{x\in X\mid f(x)\neq 0\}$ is open in $\tau$. I think I have a proof but I'm not sure about its veracity.

Let $x$ be a point on the boundary of $\text{supp}(f)^\complement=\{x\in X\mid f(x)=0\}$. If $f(x)=k\neq0$ we have that for all points $p\in\text{supp}(f)$ arbitrarily close to $x$, $k\leq d(f(x),f(p))$, but this contradicts that it is smooth, so $\text{supp}(f)$ must contain its boundary, meaning that $\text{supp}(f)$ is equal to its closure , which means it is closed, meaning that $\text{supp}(f)$ is open. Is this correct?

Comment: For any continuous map $f\colon X\to Y$ and open set $U\subseteq Y$, the se $f^{-1}(U)$ is open by definition of continuous

Comment: A remark: the support is usually defined as the *closure* of the set where $f \neq 0$, hence is (usually) *closed*. The only closed and open set in any topological space is the space itself and the emptyset. If we are not defining it this way, then the usual continuous and preimage rgument works.

Comment: @rubikscube09 "The only closed and open set in any topological space is the space itself and the empty set". This statement is not true at all. These are the only open and closed sets only in connected spaces by definition. Did you mean connected spaces?

Comment: Yes, thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something here but since $\mathbb{R}$ is a Hausdorff space it would be enough even if $f$ was just continuous. $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ so its inverse image must be open in $X$.